# I can't figure out a way to set the key on list elements from the container even though the container can very well set any other properties

Tags: reactjs

Ok so here is a simplification of my real-world use-case. Basically I have a complicated layout and I pass the layout component to the child so that it renders itself within it and then the parent layout displays it as its children. Works great, except I use this in a loop and I cannot figure out how to set the key on the children from the parent.

It's strange because I can set other properties without any issues. In the example below, the "id" property is correctly set from the list, but the console emits the warning:

**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**

```
const Child = Parent => (
  <Parent>
    The child is reponsible
    <br />
    for writing the contents.
  </Parent>
);

const present = (title) => {
  const Tag = ({ children }) => (
    <article id={title} key={title}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {children}
    </article>
  );
  
  return Child(Tag);
};

const app = (
  <div>
    {[
      'hello',
      'this',
      'is',
      'a list'
    ].map(present)}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  app,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[here's a demo of that code on codepen](https://codepen.io/djfm/pen/YzVybLR)

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

This may seem like an over-complicated way to render a template, I know, but I have - I *think* - a good real-world use-case.

Comment: Are you sure that the titles are all unique and not same/duplicated @djfm?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out.

I need to use a React.Fragment around the return value of "present",
like [so](https://codepen.io/djfm/pen/YzVybLR):

```
const present = (title) => {
  const Tag = ({ children }) => (
    <article id={title}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {children}
    </article>
  );
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={title}>
      {Child(Tag)}
    </React.Fragment>
   );
};
```

Comment: this solution removes the error; however, it creates a fragment for each iteration in map.

Comment: @Sina is that bad?

Comment: you are populating the virtualDOM with unnecessary fragment objects with O(n). this makes your code less performant & is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are providing the key to the child & not the parent of what is being rendered from the map items.
you can set key to the parent component (instead of `<article>`) as well as sending the Tag parameter:

```
const Child = (Parent, key) => (
  <Parent key={key}>
    The child is reponsible
    <br />
    for writing the contents.
  </Parent>
);
//...
const present = (title) => {
  const Tag = ({ children }) => (
    <article id={title}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      {children}
    </article>
  );
  
  return Child(Tag, title);
};
```

your solution by using a `React.Fragment` also does a similar job (setting the key for the outer wrapper (here being fragment) in rendering the list using the map method). the difference being you are creating a fragment for each iteration in the map method, but by passing the key you can avoid that as well.

Comment: Yes, I has come up with your solution myself, but I don't like it very much - no offence - because this makes the Child aware that it is actually in a loop. I want the Child to have minimal responsibilities.

Comment: @djfm in that case, you need to re-design the way you create & consume components. This doesn't seem to be a standard way of doing things with react. Think about using HOCs or builder components.